# Getting "Property X is missing in type error" in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

Getting

```
Property 'conf' is missing in type '{ text: string; label: string; }'.
```

from this object:

```ts
{
  //...
  digitalSkills: {
    skills: [
      {
        name: '...',
        tooltip: {
          text: '...',
          label: '...'
        }
      },
      {
        name: '...',
        tooltip: {
          text: '...',
          label: '...'
        }
      }
    ],
     //...
  }
  //...
}
```

from this setup:

```ts
export interface TooltipConfig {
  text:string;
  label:string;
  conf?:string;
}

export class Tooltip implements TooltipConfig {
  text:string;
  label:string;
  conf:(any);

  constructor(c:TooltipConfig) {
    this.text = c.text;
    this.label = c.label;
    c.conf && (this.conf = c.conf);
  }
}

export interface Section {
  //...
  digitalSkills?:{
    skills?:{
      name:string,
      tooltip:Tooltip
    }
}
```

My problem is I declare optional parameters in other classes the same way and they seem to work just fine. I don't understand what's wrong here and how I can fix it.

Note: I'm not after an easy fix by adding the (optional?) parameter as an empty string. I would like to know the cause of this and the general principle.

Trying to understand and learn TypeScript properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `conf` property optional in the `Tooltip` class.

```
export class Tooltip implements TooltipConfig {
  text:string;
  label:string;
  conf?:(any);

  constructor(c:TooltipConfig) {
    this.text = c.text;
    this.label = c.label;
    c.conf && (this.conf = c.conf);
  }
}
```

Or you need to use the `TooltipConfig` interface as the type for the `tooltip` property in the`Section` interface.

```
export interface Section {
  //...
  digitalSkills?:{
    skills?:{
      name:string,
      tooltip:TooltipConfig 
    }
}
```

Or you can instantiate the Tooltip class in the object creation:

```
{
  //...
  digitalSkills: {
    skills: [
      {
        name: '...',
        tooltip: new Tooltip({
          text: '...',
          label: '...'
        })
      },
      {
        name: '...',
        tooltip: new Tooltip({
          text: '...',
          label: '...'
        })
      }
    ],
     //...
  }
  //...
}
```

Take a look at this [sample code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20TooltipConfig%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20label%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20conf%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Tooltip%20implements%20TooltipConfig%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20label%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20conf%3F%3A%20(any)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(c%3A%20TooltipConfig)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.text%20%3D%20c.text%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.label%20%3D%20c.label%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c.conf%20%26%26%20(this.conf%20%3D%20c.conf)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Section%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20digitalSkills%3F%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20skills%3F%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tooltip%3A%20Tooltip%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20section%3A%20Section%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20digitalSkills%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20skills%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tooltip%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20''%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: 1. That is exactly what I need. Actually, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Do you know how I could achieve that technically? Or 2. I have tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: I edited the answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: If you look closely at my question, solution 1 is exactly my existing code. I don't understand what is the change you are proposing. Solution 2 gives the same error. I know it shouldn't but I'm looking at it and pulling my hair out. :)

Comment: In your code the Tooltip class has this property "conf:(any);" I changed to "conf?:(any);"

Comment: `conf?:(any)` doesn't work anymore in classes, since Typescript 1.6. I'm using Typescript 1.8. It's a multi-level object coming as json from an API. I can't instantiate the tooltips upon creation.

Comment: The optional parameter works on version 2.0 of typescript I'm not sure if it stopped working on version 1.8. I'll add a link to the code in Typescript playground in the answer.

Comment: Yep, it works. I guess the ts compiler is outdated. Thank you. `Error:(x,y):TS1112: A class member cannot be declared optional.` :)